# WinError 2 The system cannot find the file specified. On Sublime Text

Tags: html, css, sublimetext3

I'm currently creating a website. I'm a newbie when it comes to website building. I have two tabs which are the html, css files and my code. I'm trying to review how my code comes out on browser and I can't get a separate browser file to open. Went through build system and even downloaded chrome. My CSS file is not even applying to the html file. This is the error I get when I try to build after clicking build under Tools. When I click view in browser, nothing pops up on screen. How can I fix the error of file not specified. Help and thanks.

[image: WinError2 Image]

I've downloaded Chrome, went through the installation process of using cmd terminal to do build system. I've restarted Sublime Text. I moved the files to the original sublime folder on my computer. Still issues.

Comment: Almost certainly you were meant to replace `PATH_TO_CHOME` with the actual path to chrome; the first entry in that list is the program that it's trying to run, and that is most likely not something that actually exists.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.